# Find matches using get_close_matches() with a list contains tuples

Tags: python

I have a list which contains tuples, in each tuple there 2 elements: keyword and definition for that keyword. (This is like a dictionary). I tried to use get_close_matches() but it returned an empty list. I expected it to return something in the list.

This works for list, but I don't know how to get it work for list that contains tuples inside it? Please help.!

```
from difflib import get_close_matches

list=[('slam', 'To close violently.'), ('monish', "To scold or rebuke; to counsel in
terms of someone's behavior."), ('yellow card', 'A penalty card shown by the referee to a 
player being cautioned.'), ('fling', 'To move in an abrupt or headlong manner.')]

get_close_matches("slamm",list)
```

The output result is:

```
[]
```

I expected it to return something like this:

```
[slam]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this function in particular, but looking at the documentation [here](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/difflib.get_close_matches) it suggests that the second input should be a list of strings, not a list of tuples.  I would recommend doing something like:

1. don't name your lists "list"!  Let's call it "my_list"
2. process my_list into a list of just the keywords:

   keywords = [x[0] for x in my_list]
3. and then try calling the function on just the keywords:

   get_close_matches("slamm", keywords)

Comment: @pippo1980 the point of the function is to find strings that are close misspellings of words in the second input: hence he has misspelled "slam" as "slamm" and wants it to return the correct word

Comment: but this looks right since docs says:  difflib.get_close_matches(word, possibilities, n=3, cutoff=0.6)

    Return a list of the best “good enough” matches. word is a sequence for which close matches are desired (typically a string), and possibilities is a list of sequences against which to match word (typically a list of strings).

Comment: sorry I got it now:  print(get_close_matches("slamm", [x[0] for x in listz]))

Comment: my question now is how different can my input word be to be found ? is there any way to figure it out ?